# Want Regex to stop at first occurrence of "." and ";"

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, nlp

I am trying to extract sentence to from a paragraph, with pattern like

```
 Current. time is six thirty at Scotland. Past. time was five thirty at India; Current. time is five thirty at Scotland. Past. time was five thirty at Scotland. Current. time is five ten at Scotland.
```

When I Use Regex as

```
/current\..*scotland\./i
```

This matches to all string

```
Current. time is six thirty at Scotland. Past. time was six thirty at India; Current. time is five thirty at Scotland. Past. time was five thirty at Scotland. Current. time is five ten at Scotland.
```

Instead I want to stop at first occurrence of "." to all capture groups like

```
 Current. time is six thirty at Scotland.
 Current. time is five ten at Scotland.
```

Similarly for text like

```
 Past. time was five thirty at India; Current. time is six thirty at Scotland. Past. time was five thirty at Scotland. Past. time was five ten at India;
```

When I Use Regex Like

```
 /past\..*india\;/i
```

This matches will whole string

```
 Past. time was five thirty at India; Current. time is six thirty at Scotland. Past. time was five thirty at Scotland. Past. time was five ten at India;
```

Here I want to capture all groups or first group like following, and How to stop at first occurrence of ";"

```
Past. time was five thirty at India; 
Past. time was five ten at India;
```

How I can make regular expression to stop at "," or ";" with above examples?

Comment: Your pattern is greedy, and will match as much as it can. Make it lazy by appending a `?`, so it looks like `/current\..*?scotland\./i`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few things you shouldn't really be doing with your regex, first off, as pointed out by Arnal Murali, you shouldn't be using a greedy regex but should use the lazy version:

```
/current\..*?scotland\./i
```

I think it is a general rule of regex to go for the lazy option first as it is more often what you want. Secondly, you don't really want to use `.` to match everything, since you do not want to allow this part of your regex to match either `.` or `;` you can put those in a negative capture group to capture anything but them:

```
/current\.[^.]*?scotland\./i
```

and

```
/current\.[^;]*?india;/i
```

or cover both with:

```
/(current|past)\.[^.;]*?(india|scotland)[.;]/i
```

(obviously this might not be what you want to do, just including to demonstrate how to extend this)

This is also a good rule of thumb, if you're having trouble with a regex make any wildcards more specific (in this case changing from matching everything `.` to matching everything but `.` and `;` with `[^.;]`)

Comment: Nicely written answer +1 :)

Comment: @zx81 Thanks. always nice to hear. :)

Answer (score 3):

As Amal said, your pattern is greedy and you should append a ? to make it lazy. I'd use the following to get ONLY the first occurrence the string you ask for:

```
/^.*?current\..*?scotland\./i
```

And this to get every group following that pattern, taking into account ';' as well as '.':

```
/current\..*?scotland[.;]/i
```

This last one basically means: Find any occurrence of 'current' and stop when you reach the first 'scotland' followed by either a '.' or a ';'

Comment: No need to escape the `.` and `;` within a character class. So `/current\..*?scotland[.;]/i` would suffice.

Comment: You're correct. I was just being extra verbose early in the morning :) Edited.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = ""Current. time is six thirty at Scotland. Past. time..."
s.scan /[Current|Past]*\..*?[.|;]/i 

#=> ["Current. time is six thirty at Scotland.", "Past. time was five thirty at India;",...]
```